# CSS stylesheet class order

Tags: html, css

In my CSS stylesheet below, ".b1" doesn't work if it's after ".table".

What is the reason for this? Is there a rule to the order in the CSS stylesheet?

Thanks much

```css
.b1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="b1">Item</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: Strange it seems to work. Thanks everyone for your help. Not sure if it is because I restarted my computer or a software issue.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? There are rules to the order of CSS stylesheet (they are called "cascading") but they wouldn't be creating a problem here with the code you provided

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'm using an epub editing software called "calibre" in debian buster.
The bottom border wouldn't show when I put .b1 under .table in the css style sheet.
I can't seem to reproduce it with JSFiddle. Maybe it's a problem with Calibre?

Comment: it probably was the strange invisible character you had at the end of your css code. some editors cause this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
.table .b1 {
  // whatever
}
```

that will work because `.b1` class is nested below the `table` element.  You are trying that it is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend making the code a bit more readable.
Second, I added some more code, so that you can see that the first child is taking the style with a background of red.  You can remove it later, but it helps for testing purposes. Try this out:

```
table td:first-child {text-align: left; background-color: red;} 
.b1 {border-bottom: 5px solid black; }

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="b1">Item </td>
            <td class="b1">Item 2 </td>
            <td class="b1">Item 3 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```